# how I can add Image.png to my project in NetBeans using GTK+?

Tags: c++, linux, netbeans, gtk

for now I'm loading images using gtk_image_new_from_file() function, but I want my images to be embedded in my app.

Comment: Why do you want such stuff? It's better to have the image in a separate file!

Comment: What do you mean with "embedded", inside the object code file, then as the comment before, Why do you want such a stuff

Comment: @erick2red in windows we use resources to store images or any other data like icons, text files etc. I need something like this, bcz I dont want to keep my app with 40 icons placed around my app in same dir.

Comment: @anthony612 Don't have to be in your app dir but in a subdir called _res/icons_

Comment: @erick2red but if i got 1000 images? anyway I think to store this outside of executable is really bad thing

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at gdk-pixbuf-csource which can convert images into C code allowing you to inline them in the binary. The documentation at http://developer.gnome.org/gdk-pixbuf/2.23/gdk-pixbuf-Inline-data.html explains it in more detail